# Changes to parents not cascading to relationship child

Tags: playa, relationships, children

Got a large number of relationships in a DB via Playa.

When I change a parent entry (the titles) the title been out-put by the playa tag is still the title before it has changed.

I know why this is happening as the old title is stored in the playa entry, but is there a way to make playa automatically go round and check and update these so I can change these without having to do it manually.

So to clarify:

Channel 'Parent' has a entry "I'm the Daddy"
Channel 'Child' has an entry which via playa references "I'm the Daddy"

If I rename the entry in the parent channel to "I'm not the daddy", when I reference the parent's title via the child using playa, it returns "I'm the daddy" still instead of using the updated title.

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching in your template ([tag caching](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/caching.html#tag-caching) or [template caching](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/caching.html#id2))?

Comment: Nope, all caching is disabled and the first thing I did after making the change was clear all the cacheing.

Also I can see in the DB where it is storing the old title in the actual playa tag.

Comment: Does the title change in the CP (for example, editing the entry where the relationship was made)?

Comment: Yes and re-submitting the entry corrects it. What I want is a way to make it do this without having to manually resubmit every entry.

Comment: Anyone? Can't believe there isn't a way to do this as its a major flaw with Playa where old data gets stuck in the Playa fields..... Really need a way to make playa just go through and check all the titles it has are current.

Comment: Perhaps there is some server-level caching at work? I can tell you from experience that this is not normal Playa behaviour - an update to an entry should be reflected on the front-end immediately.

Comment: There is no caching, its due to the way Playa works, when you save an entry with playa, it doesn't just store the ID of the entry, it saves the title and URL_title as well in the playa field. 

So when you pull it back the title or URL_title back, it just grabs the ones in the playa field instead of actually tracking it back to the field in question.

Its standard playa functionality as far as I can tell... Surprised me a bit it was made to work this way as well.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you are incorrect here. Playa does store that info in `exp_channel_data`, but mainly as search metadata. `exp_playa_relationships` stores the canonical relationship info, and Playa fetches the full entry data based on the parent/child `entry_id` when you call the tag. What you are experiencing is *not* expected Playa behaviour.

Comment: Well, thats whats happening in Playa on the last 3 EE sites I've built that use it, am using the standard tags from the playa documentation.

Comment: If you are talking about 9+ months ago, the older version didn't store this extra information so didn't do this.

Comment: Using Playa 4.4.5 and EE 2.6.1, on a site I'm developing  right now, updates to parent/child entries in the CP are reflected on the front-end immediately.

Comment: Are you pulling in the titles? Its only the actual title that isn't been updated, all other fields are.

Comment: Drenzul, did you found a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: Please, do not post comments as answers. This makes more difficult for others users to find answers. Thanks.

Comment: No, I'm actually manually updating the databases as needed since I couldn't find an answer for this at all. The only thing I could find that made sense was to write a bit of code to do this for me, but it doesn't need updating very often so I'm doing it manually ;)